# Map return value of function calls to object attribute

Tags: python

I'm confronted with a class object that has many attributes that need to be filled with the return value of individual function calls. Unfortunately the attribute names don't map one to one to parameters of the called functions. Is there a pythonic way to achieve this without doing this manual mapping repeatedly?

```
obj = MyClass()
obj.a_min = func(a1xyz, 'min')
obj.a_max = func(a2zzz, 'max')
obj.a_avg = ...
obj.b_min = ...
obj.b_max = ...
...
obj.n_min = ...
...
```

Comment: `obj.b_min = ...` ?  what should the ellipsis be there?  `func(b1xyz,min)`?

Comment: Is there any repetition here at all? Is it always the same `func()`?

Comment: Is `max` the built-in `max` function or some variable? Likewise for `min`? Where do the `a1xzy`, `a2zzz` come from? Are they local variables? Do they come from a dictionary? Properties of another object?

Comment: @Dirk I edited the initial post. The min/max are not the builtin functions but rather directives to/modes of the function.

Comment: @mgilson: _a1xyz_ and so on are local variables that resemble but differ slightly from the objects attributes.
With the elipsis I wanted to indicate that repetition of the previous line is happening with the only variation that the function parameters differ slightly.

Comment: @bfloriang -- I understand that, but the variation in the parameter names is critical to solving this "problem".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the most pythonic way to do it but here is one alternative which is working as long as the functions you want to call have the same signature :

```
class A(object) :
    def __init__(self) :
        d = {"arg1" : (1, "arg1_v"),
             "arg2" : (2, "arg2_v")}
        for key, value in d.items() :
            setattr(self, key, f(*value))

a = A()
print a.arg1
print a.arg2
```

You can even use a function name if you want to call different functions depending on the attribute name :

```
def f_arg1(x) :
    return x
def f_arg2(x, y) :
    return (x, y)

class A(object) :
    def __init__(self) :
        d = {"arg1" : ((1,), f_arg1),
             "arg2" : ((2,3), f_arg2)}
        for key, value in d.items() :
            a, f = value
            setattr(self, key, f(*a))

a = A()
print a.arg1
print a.arg2
```